# Scraping dynamic content through Selenium?

Tags: javascript, html, python-2.7, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrap dynamic content from a [Blog](http://justgivemechocolateandnobodygetshurt.blogspot.com/) through Selenium but it always returns un rendered JavaScript.

To test this behavior I tried to wait till iframe loads completely and printed it's content which prints fine but again when I move back to parent frame it just displays un rendered JavaScript.

I'm looking for something in which I'm able to print completely rendered HTML content

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions

driver = webdriver.Chrome("path to chrome driver")   
driver.get('http://justgivemechocolateandnobodygetshurt.blogspot.com/')

WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(expected_conditions.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "navbar-iframe")))

# Rendered iframe HTML is printed.
content = driver.page_source
print content.encode("utf-8")

# When I switch back to parent frame it again prints non rendered JavaScript.
driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
content = driver.page_source
print content.encode("utf-8")
```

Comment: because `.page_source` returns the source, not the DOM

Comment: @Fabricator How can I get the updated DOM?

Comment: @UmarIqbal, Have you tried selecting the element using one of the `find_element` methods?

Comment: I think any of the [`find_element*`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html#locating-elements) commands should do

Comment: or you can just execute [javascript code](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html?highlight=javascript#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script)

Comment: `execute_script('return document.documentElement.outerHTML')` doesn't render and with `find_element` I'll have to traverse whole DOM, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is - [the `.page_source` works only in the current context](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#getting-page-source). There is that ["current top-level browsing context"](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#dfn-current-top-level-browsing-context) notation..Meaning, if you would call it on a default content - you would not get the inner HTML of the child `iframe`elements - for that you would have to switch into the context of a `frame` and call `.page_source`.

In other words, to get the very complete HTML of the page including the page source of the iframes, you would have to switch into the iframe contexts one by one and get the sources separately.

See also:

- [Command Contexts](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#h-command-contexts)
- [Switch To Frame](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#switch-to-frame)

---

**Old answer:**

I would [wait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) for at least one blog entry to be loaded before getting the `page_source`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 40)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".entry-content")))

print(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: Doesn't matter, still returns the old DOM.

Comment: @UmarIqbal okay, what do you mean by the old DOM? And what is your desired output?

Comment: by old DOM I meant un rendered JavaScript. All I want is a completely rendered HTML content.

Comment: @UmarIqbal thanks, could you be more specific and point to an, perhaps, element you don't want to see in the page source? Note that even if I go to the website, wait for it to load and inspect the page source - I would still see the script tags with javascript there.

Comment: Can you try running my code? the first print statement prints the dynamically loaded iframe. 
After that in second print statement I print the complete page source, It's supposed to print complete DOM along with that iframe but it doesn't.

Comment: @UmarIqbal ah, sure, the `page_source` would not get you the inner iframe's sources. You would have to switch to iframe and call `page_source` to access the HTML inside the iframe..that's just how it works.

Comment: But since Selenium uses browser agents and we can see all the content when we inspect element, why cannot we just get it from DOM or `driver.page_source`?

Comment: @UmarIqbal okay, let me update the answer to reflect our conversation a bit. Thanks.