# Why does my scraper return none with beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.7

I'm trying to extract the table from this website https://www.solarreviews.com/solar-panels/solar-panel-cost/ the solar energy price from every state and pass it into a CSV file. Here is the code so far. It's returning 'None'. Can someone please explain to me why? And what to do? I would greatly appreciate this.

````
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import csv

#Open page and grab HTML
my_url = ('https://www.solarreviews.com/solar-panels/solar-panel-cost/')
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#HTML parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')

#Find table
ele_table = page_soup.find('table',{"class":"table table-hover stateAveragesTable"})

print(ele_table)```
````

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scraping dynamic content through Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36779288/scraping-dynamic-content-through-selenium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the tr style attributes so all show. Note that you also risk IP banning if you make too many requests.

```
import requests,re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://www.solarreviews.com/solar-panels/solar-panel-cost/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
table_html = str(soup.select_one('.stateAveragesTable'))
table_html = re.sub('display: none;','', table_html)
print(pd.read_html(str(table_html)))
```