# Selenium aspx results

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer, dom, viewstate

I'm new to selenium, so apologies if the question isn't well formed.
I'm looking at automating some data gathering. There is an ASP.NET site, where you can request data about a specific topic. When the data query completes the web page is updated with the results. When I use selenium to get the page_source, I don't see the data. I believe it's encoded in the __VIEWSTATE. Using IE DOM Explorer, the data is there in plain text.

Is there a way to pull the data from the DOM Explorer? Basically, I'd be happy to get a dump and parse it myself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you view the page source, isn't "view state" just a single `<input type="hidden">`?  If that's the value you're looking for, wouldn't you get it like any other `<input>` value in Selenium?  What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: If the data isn't in the initial page source but is in the displayed result in your browser then it sounds like it's being dynamically added.  It could be elsewhere in the page source and re-formatted by code, it could be in the JavaScript, it could be in a separate AJAX call, etc.  You need to reverse-engineer the page from which you're trying to scrape data.  In your browser's debugging tools, does it make additional HTTP calls?  Do any of those calls include the data?  Does it reference other resources?  Do any of those contain the data?

Comment: I submit a request on a form to get some client information back. I do `driver.page_source`. What I was expecting, is the client data is in the page_source. This way I can just parse the HTML and extract the client data. But it's not there. So then I go to IE and hit f12. There are multiple tabs there, "DOM Explorer", "DEBUG", etc. When I look at the DOM Explorer it has all the client data. However, when I look at the "DEBUG" tab I see the data which I got back in page_source which has multiple __VIEWSTATE entries, but I can't see the actual client data in clear text.

Comment: Which means the data isn't in the initial page source, it's coming from somewhere else.  You have to find where.  Reverse-engineering a web page isn't always an easy task, they can have highly dynamic functionality.  My guess would be that the data is likely fetched from an AJAX request made by the page, or referenced in another file used by the page.  You'll need to examine the additional network requests made in the browser's debugging tools when loading the page.

Comment: Sorry, new to web technology. I do see a bunch of Java script calls. I don't have access to the system at the moment, so I can't delve into it. But when you say the data is dynamically added. Do you mean there are further server calls to get the data. However, the client data is already displayed on screen, wouldn't that mean it has already been fetched? Are you saying I'll need to refetch the data? (sorry if these are noob questions)

Comment: "Already been fetched" could take literally milliseconds.  It could fetch the data faster than it renders the page.  To a human observer looking at a browser window there may be no discernable difference.  But when reverse-engineering the functionality in code it makes all the difference.  If the data isn't in the page source then it's somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. I'll have to do a more detailed pass over the html code. However, still one thing is unclear to me. The data can be viewed in the DOM Explorer. Do you know if the IE webdriver for selenium provides an ability to extract the same data displayed in the DOM Explorer. It seems to me that the data is there, since IE has the ability to display it in the DOM Explorer. What am I missing?

Comment: It may depend on how you're using Selenium, and I don't know enough about it to be particularly specific.  If it's interacting with the browser then you may be unintentionally telling it to examine the page source instead of the DOM?  Or if it's not interacting with the browser but rather requesting the page itself then it's likely not also executing the JavaScript code and making additional requests like the browser does.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Selenium and all this web scrapping stuff (just started yesterday :) ). I was doing some web searches and I see there is a way to enable/disable DOM storage in IE. They liken it to cookies. I'm assuming that means the DOM tree is cached somewhere. I'm trying to find where in the file system it's storing the DOM tree. Any ideas? My current hunch, is if I know where they are storing it, I can just read it off the file system directly.

Comment: For selenium from what I've been observing, it directly controls the browser. There are browser drivers which provide some functionality, like extracting elements etc. However, from my testing it appears like all the information it's extracting is from the page source. That's why I was wondering if the IE driver provides a way to extract the DOM tree. Couldn't find any documentation on it.

Comment: This question may be a bit defunct at this point, having an extended comment thread which has deviated a bit from the posted question.  But you may be onto something that can be used to formulate a new question.  Consider three key pieces of information: (1) The code you're using to (try to) read the DOM, (2) The elements in the page source, (3) The elements you observe in the DOM explorer.  From there a very reasonable question would simply be something like, "I'm trying to read the DOM from Selenium, but it's only seeint the page source.  How do I get the current DOM state?" (Elaborate more)

Comment: Of course include minimal but useful copies of those three pieces of information (as text, not screen shots) and describe specifically what you're observing in your debugging efforts and the data you're trying to read.

Comment: I agree with your analysis and the core of the problem. Do you mean I should post a new question on stackoverflow?

Comment: That would probably be best, yes.  You're likely to get more attention from a new question containing that information than from editing this one with its long comment thread.  This one should just be deleted, but at the very least it was hopefully the start of something helpful.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks for all your time. Very helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: If possible try to post the HTML source code and your Selenium code. Also, let us know what is the expected output. We will try to check and test the code and try to provide suggestions for it.

Comment: sounds like you want to use a WebDriverWait along with ExpectedConditions for whatever elements you need.  Selenium does poll the current DOM, but a wait is needed when a standard page load does not happen.  WebDriverWait is a special kind of wait that polls the DOM every 1/2 second to look for certain expected conditions.  If a user-specified timeout period is reached before the expected condition evaluates to true, it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out. Thanks for all the input. I got clued in to the answer from this: [Scraping dynamic content through Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36779288/scraping-dynamic-content-through-selenium)

What I ended up doing is first get the list of iframes on the page

```
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")
```

Then switch to each iframe one at a time. In my case the first iframe was the one with the relevant information:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")[0])
```

Once I was in the relevant frame then I could do:

```
html = driver.page_source
```

And that would give me the expected result.

It appears like the frame context is important. Once you're in the frame context then you could scrape the data.